# Determine the state of a machine over time

Tags: probability

We study over time the state of a machine obeying the following rules:

- If the machine is working at the moment $n-1$, it has probability $\dfrac{1}{
  6}$ to be faulty at the moment $n$.
- If the machine is faulty at the moment $n-1$, it has probability $\dfrac{2}{
  3}$
  to be faulty at the moment $n$.

Denote $p_n$ the probability that the machine is working at the moment $n$.

Question: Determine a relation between $p_n$ an $p_{n-1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N^*$.

My try:

Let $W_n$ the event "the machine is working on the moment $n$".

Let  $F_n$ the event "the machine is faulty on the moment $n$".

Then the two systems $\Omega_n=\{W_n,F_n\}$ and $\Omega_{n-1}=\{W_{n-1},F_{n-1}\}$ are two complete systems of events and then we have by the formula of total probability:

$$p(F_n)=p(F_n|W_{n-1})p(W_{n-1})+p(F_n|F_{n-1})p(F_{n-1})=\dfrac{1}{6}W_{n-1}+\dfrac{2}{3}F_{n-1}$$
Now since $p(F_n)=1-p(W_n)=1-p_n$ and $F_{n-1}=1-W_{n-1}$ then we get
$$p_n=\dfrac{1}{2}p_{n-1}+\dfrac{1}{3}$$

Is my try correct? Thank your for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use fewer symbols, and duplicate your result, which is correct. The machine can be working at time $n$ in two disjoint ways: (i) It was working at time $n-1$, and is still working or (ii) It was not working at time $n-1$, but has been fixed.

The probability of (i) is $(p_{n-1})(5/6)$.

The probability of (ii) is $(1-p_{n-1})(1/3)$.

Comment: In calculating i) for example you assume that working on time $n-1$ and on time $n$ are independent events so that the intersection is merely the product of the two probabilities which seems to be not the case in the problem which links working on time $n$ with that of time $n-1$. Also what do you use as a probabilistic formula to take the sum of i) and ii) ? and why are i) and ii) disjoint even if both consider the machine is working on time $n$?

Comment: We did not use independence, we used your conditional probability argument without explicitly mentioning it, since it is of an elementary nature. We are told that **given** the machine is working at time $n-1$, the probability it is not working at time $n$ is $1/6$, and therefore the probability it is working is $5/6$. Thus the probability it is working at time $n-1$ **and** working at time $n$ is $(p_{n-1})(5/6)$. As to your second question, they are disjoint, (i) involves the machine working at time $n-1$, and (ii) involves the machine not working at time $n-1$.

Comment: You are welcome. You had actually done absolutely all the work.